# ngTagsInput "ngrepeat: dupes" and "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am attempting to use autocomplete inside ngTagsInput and I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=item%20in%20suggestionList.items%20track%20by%20track(item)&p1=undefined
    at Error (native)
```

OR

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at j (https://localhost:3000/js/plugins/ng-tags-input.min.js:1:5556)
```

I have checked several time that my querying function is returning a proper array of tags, and it is. It works beautifully. The structure of a tag looks like:

```
{ 
name: String, 
_id: ObjectId, 
__v: Number, 
active: Boolean, 
display: Boolean, 
createDate: Date
}
```

My html looks like:

```
<tags-input
    ng-model="tags"
    displayProperty="name"
    placeholder="Add a tag">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

And my loadTags function is:

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {

    return $http.get(configService.getApi() + '/tags?conditions=' + urlEncodeObject({name: { $regex: query }}), {
        headers: {
            'x-auth-token': sessionService.getToken()
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: which plugin you are using.Can we have your code in http://plnkr.co/ so that we can resolve it faster?

Comment: using this plugin: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput. let me try to get some kind of fiddle going, although i'm not sure how to do the backend stuff.

Comment: Hardcoded those backend stuff in plunkr...

Answer (score 5):

displayProperty should have been display-property. Doh!

Comment: I had a custom json and just couldn't figure out what went wrong until I found this display-property ! Life-saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Dupes - it mean index for ngRepeat is duplicated.
You have to use smth like

`ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`

Comment: But how are we supposed to do that, given that all the repetition is taken care by `auto-complete` directive?

Comment: indeed you can't

Answer (score 1):

```js
// ng-repeat not check [key-property="text"]
// <tags-input ng-model="ruzhu_ids"  class="ui-tags-input"   placeholder=" "  
// add-from-autocomplete-only="false"
// key-property="text"
// > 
// </tags-input> 
// before you change tags,check dup self ,make text unique 
var can_add_tag = true;
angular.forEach($scope.ruzhu_ids, function(data, index) {
  if (data.text == result.text) {
    can_add_tag = false;
  }
});
if (can_add_tag) {
  $scope.ruzhu_ids.push(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On tags-input add key-property="key" where key value is unique to each object.

```
<tags-input
    ng-model="tags"
    displayProperty="name"
    key-property="id" /* here id is a key with unique value */
    placeholder="Add a tag">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```